# Set next statement unavailable when debugging in visual studio 2013 Update 5

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

After updating Visual Studio Ultimate to Update 5, the set next statement option no longer appears when right clicking during a debug session, nor does ctrl-shift F10 work. When I use my assigned key combination I get message that my key combo is bound to a command (Set Next Statement) which is not currently available.

This behavior occurs in all projects include those where Target CPU is set to x86 in the Compile Tab of the project

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I am using visual basic